# Number of processors in a multi-core CPU with hyper-threading

Tags: cpu, multi-core, hyper-threading

I've been reading [*What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory*](https://people.freebsd.org/~lstewart/articles/cpumemory.pdf) by U. Drepper, where they state the following on p. 3:

> Red Hat, as of 2007, expects that for
>   future products, the “standard building blocks” for most
>   data centers will be a computer with up to four sockets,
>   each filled with a quad core CPU that, in the case of Intel
>   CPUs, will be hyper-threaded.<sup>2</sup> This means the standard
>   system in the data center will have up to 64 virtual processors.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>2</sup> Hyper-threading enables a single processor core to be used for two or more concurrent executions with just a little extra hardware.

What I'm unclear about is how such a system would have 64 (virtual) processors.

Let us even assume that a hyper-threaded CPU consists of 2 processors (I've read about this technology, so I know that it may even perform worse, and at most about 30% faster than a non-hyper-threaded CPU). A quad-core consists of 4 processors, so a device with 4 hyper-threaded quad-core CPUs would have 4 * 2 * 4 = 32 processors.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement doesn't contain any reference to the number of cores per CPU.

64 virtual processors / 4 sockets / 2 (HT) would mean that each CPU would have to have 8 cores. 2008 just a year after the date mentioned in that excert there were already [6 core CPUs available](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/codename/25006/dunnington.html). The write probably though that later on 8 cores (at least) would be doable.

Comment: Sure does, "each filled with a **quad core CPU**"? Do you think the last sentence there (before the footnote) refers to a different kind of system?

Comment: Indeed that's odd but probably simply something that slipped by or another extrapolation based on having HT (yes the footnote wouldn't fit). As far as I know there have been rumors about AMD working on HT with up to four threads.

Comment: The statement by Red Hat was a prediction made in 2007.  I mean the footnote is incorrect, due to the fact, there are no processors  with hyper-threading that exceed 2 threads per core even in 2019.  In fact based on the current leaks we any product in 2020 that can do more than 2 threads per core.

Comment: It seems IBM POWER8 processors have up to 8 threads per core - see this [anandtech article](https://www.anandtech.com/show/10435/assessing-ibms-power8-part-1/4)